# How to RAM efficiently load spacy models into fastapi with gunicorn?

Tags: gunicorn, spacy, fastapi

I am having challenges with my fastapi server running out of RAM after updating to use the `spacy_en_core_web_lg` from the small model.

When running fastapi 4 gunicorn workers are spawned and based on the memory usage I think each worker is loading in the model. Is there a way I can share the model across workers so I don't need to load it in each?

Comment: Make a separate thread or whatever with the model and have everyone talk to it. If that's complicated, set up a separate server with the model and one worker and have everyone talk to that.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about having a dedicated server for the model -- definitely complicates things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is what has helped in my case. YMMV, particularly because I have not used Spacy directly but PyTorch.

I wrote a longer form post about this topic here: http://www.streppone.it/cosimo/blog/2021/08/deploying-large-deep-learning-models-in-production/

Here's a summary:

- Use gunicorn `preload_app = True` option, to have gunicorn load your application *before* the workers `fork()`
- Load the model before the FastAPI application is created
- If the model is PyTorch based, use `model.eval()` and `model.share_memory()`. See further documentation here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html
- Limit the amount of workers (which you are already doing). Three workers was best for me. Four also seems reasonable, it really depends on your project and requirements
- Limit the lifetime of each worker through gunicorn `max_requests`. In my case, I noticed a sharp increase of memory usage for each worker after some time, so this option curbs that behaviour.

Further links and reading in the post I mentioned. I would be very interested in feedback about these tips, because so far I haven't been able to find any good references online.

Comment: Great idea to limit the worker lifetime with `max_requests` long running spacy models used to leak memory! Looking at the gunicorn docs, I have set preload to true and it has already helped!

Comment: That's awesome! Glad I could be of help @swartchris8